# Preposition 'to' with gerund (-ing)?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

Check this sentence from [Ed.gov](https://www.ed.gov/oii-news/use-technology-teaching-and-learning) (US Department of Education)

> Technology ushers in fundamental structural changes that can be integral **to achieving** significant improvements in productivity.

Cannot it be better as...

> Technology ushers in fundamental structural changes that can be integral **to achieve** significant improvements in productivity.

The preposition *to* takes *gerund (-ing)* here. Any rule?

Answer (score 4):

It is not just the preposition *to* that takes the gerund, but the construction "be *adjective* to":

> Locking him up without food or water **is** tantamount **to** *killing* him.
>   Knowing your budget **is** important **to** successfully *planning* your holiday.

There are lists of verbs that take an infinitive or a gerund, like [here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/verblist.htm), but they are seldom complete.

The gerund is also after verbs like "looking forward to":

> I look forward to *meeting* you
>   He looks forward to *getting* to know her better.

Let's have a look at another example sentence to see if there is a difference between "be *adjective* to *gerund*" and "be _adjective infinitive":

> Sharp knifes **are** important **to** *cooking*.
>   Sharp knifes **are** important *to cook*.

In the first sentence, I state that an important part of the action of *cooking* consists of *sharp knifes*. The sharp knifes can be seen as a property of *cooking*.

The second sentence is different. Well, there is the possible confusion that I mean I should cook my knifes, for one. That makes little sense.
Even if we ignore that, I would parse the sentence more like:

> If I am to cook, it is important I have sharp knifes.

So if I have no sharp knives, I won't start cooking.

Somehow, the sentence gives me more of a *specific* feeling, whereas the *cooking* variant is a general observation.

Now, in your original sentence:

> changes **are** integral **to** *achieving* improvements.
>   changes **are** integral *to achieve* improvements.

The first sentence makes *changes* an (integral) property of "achieving improvements" in general.

The second one seems to presuppose we have a specific situation where we want to achieve improvements, and in order to do that, we need *changes*.

Comment: I'm aware of *verb patterns* and have answered several questions here on this board. What confuses me is not the verb pattern *verb + -ing* **but** *preposition + ing.*

Comment: But it is _not_ just the preposition :) There is a verb there. _To be [adjective] to_ takes the gerund. "to" on its own does not.

Comment: Okay, what you think of replacing *achieve* as my second concern? Will it make it ungrammatical?

Comment: I hope my addition is somewhat useful :)

Comment: Oh yeah. that is. +1

Comment: Just to say that "are integral to achieve" and "sharp knives are important to cook" would not only be considered non-grammatical by me (British English speaker) but sound unpleasantly wrong to my ear and would mark the user as non-native.